# Googlecharts - Plotting existing PHP arrays with googlecharts

Tags: php, google-visualization

I'm in doubt about something with google charts, when i use addRows command, is it enough that my php variable be in the required format?

I'll put the code i'm working with:

```
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        google.load("visualization", "1.0",{"packages":["corechart"]});

        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart(){
            //create the data table
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn("string","Fruits");
            data.addColumn("number","Amount");
            data.addRows([<?php echo "'$jsRows'";?>]);

            //set chart options
            var options = {"title":"Amount of different fruits",
                "width":400,
                "height":300};

            //instantiate and draw chart, passing in options
            var options = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            } //end of drawchart function
            </script>
```

When i write: `echo $jsRows`; i get: `["0 as 6 h",0],["6 as 12h",0],["12 as 18h",8],["18 as 24h",0]`, which is a data format google chart can handle, but with this code, my chart doesn't appear. Does anyone have any idea why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the quotes from around the `$jsRows` variable.  Using quotes turns the array into a string, which is not compatible with the `#addRows` method.  Do this:

```
data.addRows([<?php echo $jsRows;?>]);
```